# How to make socket communication between QTcpSocket and php?

Tags: php, c++, qt, qtcpsocket

I have a simple `QTcpServer` that receives connections from a php script, hands over the socket id to a worker, gets moved to another thread and should perform a series of tasks (mainly shell scripts) then returns output to the php client. Communications between client and server would be through json encoded objects.

What I need is a simple protocol for reading/writing on both sides (i.e. in php and Qt c++) to the sockets. All tutorials and examples I have found talk about Qt client to Qt server communication (I have read all the Fortune Server etc. examples).

Comment: What do you need in addition to JSON? Post the code you already have.

Comment: If performance and size of data counts, use google's protocol buffers.